# can not resolve style from master page's pageload

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a page login.aspx in a folder which is linked to masterpage.  In the page load event of masterpage I have added some styles.  When I redirect to login.aspx, it is just not able to get the styles from the masterpage's pageload event.  I analysed the problem found that because my login.aspx is not in root folder, but in a folder which is inside root folder.

How do I run masterpage's pageload event in login.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

If the code works when you move the code to your templatized page (**not** the but the one that uses it) then it suggests that you are using a relative link for the stylesheet.

I'd recommend using a relative URL off the root (something in the form of "/stylesheet.css") so that when you have pages that use the template, but in a subdirectory, it can resolve the stylesheet correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can place all your style sheets in a folder structure as follows:

```
App_Themes/Style/mystylesheet.css
```

Then in your content ASPX pages, just add `Theme="Style"` to the page directives and ASP.NET will automatically resolve it for every page that you have :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about CSS stylesheets, and not ASP.NET styles (themes).

In that case, you can using a tag like the following from your Master page:

```
<link runat="server" rel="Stylesheet" href="~/scripts/common.css"
    type="text/css" />
```

Or you can insert the same tag programmatically from your `Page_Load()` handler.  However, in that case, it's best if you add the HtmlLink control to the Head control.  Alternatively, you can add an ID to the control and use `Visible="True"` to control whether it appears in the generated markup.

Comment: Hi Rick, just bought your new ASP.NET book and it rocks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the  section of the markup is located in the Master Page, so the reference to the StyleSheet cannot be made

```
Dim link As New HtmlLink
link.Href = "LocationOfStyleSheet.css"
link.Attributes.Add(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel.ToString(), "stylesheet")
Page.Header.Controls.Add(link)
```